# fulltext query only works "with query expansion"

Tags: mysql, search

I am trying to build a very basic fulltext search app in php. I have found an example here [Mysql  fulltext search](http://tips4php.net/2010/03/create-your-own-fulltext-searchengine-with-php-and-mysql/)  so I used it to build my own.

This is my table/data (field types are text)

```
name                                                            site result
RRR1 COS COSMETICS P R15-500 000847719903 20110607 094742.VER   RRR1 P
RRR3 BIST MIDDLEWARE P R22-200 029051946829 20110607 101331.VER     RRR3 P
RRR2 PRE PREHEAT F R16-500 000897546214 20110607 085111.VER     RRR2 F
RRR1 COS COSMETICS P R16-300 000899331425 20110607 091337.VER   RRR1 P
```

This is my index

```
ALTER TABLE automation_search_test ADD FULLTEXT search_idx (name ,site)
```

This is my query

```
SELECT * FROM automation_search_test WHERE MATCH (name,site) AGAINST ('RRR1' with query expansion);
```

I have however a few problems:

1. If I remove `with query expansion`, the query returns an empty set
2. If I add the RESULT column to my fulltext index,  the query returns an
   empty set after I change my SQL to this

> SELECT * FROM automation_search_test WHERE MATCH (name,site,result)
>   AGAINST ('RRR1' with query expansion);

Is my index incorrectly setup? Is there an issue with the data?

I welcome any input you have. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not enough data was my problem. Mysql  documentation clearly explains it. Thread closed.